# What setup is needed for a macOS app so it appears in any other app's "Open With" menu?

Tags: xcode, macos

**Problem** A macOS app built in Swift (using Xcode) shall show up in the "Open With" context menu for any file. But it does not show up at all.

**Current status**
The app has a document type for `public.item` defined.

```xml
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Any file</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Default</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.item</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
            <string>NSDocument</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

When I start the app (from Xcode), no file has my app in the "Open With" menu. I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to add a custom type. But not any tutorial for a public type. Is this even possible?

**Actual question:**
How can I configure a macOS app to show up in the "Open With" menu for any file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233933/open-any-file-in-cocoa

Comment: Thanks for sharing this one. I tried. Still the same. I also created a build through Apple notarization and moved it to the applications dir just in case the registration only works from there. But still the same issue.

Comment: I tried adding a lot of the other base types now, like public.content, public.archive, ... . This works. So I could just add all of them. But it seems public.item alone will not work.